# How to add "Request additional info" functionality in Drupal Commerce

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-commerce, drupal-webform

I'm migrating a shop from oscommerce to drupal commerce. One of the functionalities that I can't make so far is requesting information about a particular product.
In oscommerce there was just a button in the product view and when the user clicked it he was taken to a new form where he/she could fill out name/phone number/email and ask a specific question.

I started trying out the commerce webform module but I does not exactly do what I want. It should automatically gather information about the product (including the line items) from the product display and not have the user choose it again.

Is there a way to do this with the webform (or any other module) or does this require programming a new module?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly. Your solution is to pre-fill some webform fields (maybe hidden) with data from the referrer url. I beleive you may want to look at the Default value of fields and the tokens available. e.g.

```
%get[key]
```

Passing the form values when you call it and placing this in the default value of a hidden field would provide you with the info you need that will be submitted by the webform.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a custom form here which saves a new node for additional info request. This node will have the product as product reference.

This will be simple & displaying can be handled through views. You can contribute such a module too